# What should IComparer return to indicate "keep the existing sort order"

Tags: c#, icomparer

I'm implementing a custom [comparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icomparer.aspx) in order to apply a custom sort order for items in various views.

Some of the time I'm finding that I want to maintain the existing order of items, in this case what should I return from my `Compare` method implementation? Is it enough to simply return 0, or do I actively need to identify which item came first?

Comment: I'm pretty sure returning 0 will leave adjacent items as-is

Comment: @valverij Thats what I *think*, however according to the documentation that technically means `x` *equals* `y`, which in theory means that the sorter can put those two items in whatever order it chooses

Comment: It depends on what you use to do the ordering, `Enumerable.OrderBy` does a stable sort, `List<T>.Sort` is not stable, so it could re-order equal elements.

Comment: @Lee Fantastic, just found [stability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability) in wikipedia, plus notes in the [OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549422.aspx) and [Sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/w56d4y5z.aspx) documentation explaining that they are stable and not stable respectively - that answers my question perfectly

Comment: @Justin, rather than relying on other interested users reading the comments, it would be worth adding a quick answer to your own question so people know there's something useful here. Interesting question, too!

Comment: @Alex I was waiting to see if Lee converted his comment into an answer first

Comment: @Justin fair enough, just thought I'd point it out in case it turned into a fire-and-forget question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Credit for this answer goes to [Lee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15883112/what-should-icomparer-return-to-indicate-keep-the-existing-sort-order#comment22613032_15883112))

It depends on whether or not the algorithm used to do the sorting is [stable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability).  For example, the [OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549422.aspx) is stable and so returning 0 from `Compare` will mean that the two items retain their original order in the list, however [List.Sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/w56d4y5z.aspx) is not, and so returning 0 from `Compare` doesn't guarentee that the two items will be in their original order in the sorted output.

Answer (score 1):

Zero, but your sort algorithm may still change its order.